# Como ler um documento do Firestore?

Tags: android, firestore

Preciso saber como ler um documento específico que salvei no `Firestore`, sem precisar copiar o "documentPath" manualmente do Console do Cloud Firestore!

Como faz isso de forma automática?

A seguir, coloquei parte do código onde está o "documentPath" que preciso configurar:

```
DocumentReference user = mFirestore.collection("Usuarios").document(idUsuario).collection("Empresas").document(**"documentPath"**)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim db As FirestoreDb = FirestoreDb.Create(projectId)

    Dim dadosCollections = dbCollections.BuscarColecoesFirebase(projectId)

    For Each eDados As NCollections In dadosCollections
        nColecao = eDados.Collections
        nDocumentReference = eDados.DocumentReferencia
    Next

    Dim docUsuario As CollectionReference = db.Collection(nColecao)
    Dim DocLista As DocumentReference = docUsuario.Document(Alertas.EmailUsuario)
    Dim mapCloudFirestore As New SPush

    'Dim docUsuario1 As CollectionReference = DocLista.Collection(nDocumentReference)
    'Dim verificaDocument As DocumentReference = docUsuario1.Document

    Dim Query As Query = docUsuario.WhereEqualTo("StatusLido", "N")

    Dim QuerySnapshot As QuerySnapshot = Await Query.GetSnapshotAsync()
    For Each documentSnapshot As DocumentSnapshot In QuerySnapshot.Documents

        Dim doc As String = documentSnapshot.Id
        Dim snapshot As DocumentSnapshot = Await DocLista.GetSnapshotAsync()
    Next
```

faço dessa forma em vb.net veja se da uma luz ai pra vc.

Comment: Seria útil se juntasse uma pequena explicação a esse código.

Comment: Você pode explicar o que esse código faz?

Comment: ele faz uma consulta em um documento firebase

 Dim Query As Query = docUsuario.WhereEqualTo("StatusLido", "N")

    Dim QuerySnapshot As QuerySnapshot = Await Query.GetSnapshotAsync()
    For Each documentSnapshot As DocumentSnapshot In QuerySnapshot.Documents

        Dim doc As String = documentSnapshot.Id
        Dim snapshot As DocumentSnapshot = Await DocLista.GetSnapshotAsync()
    Next